# Remove gap from bottom of fluid flex containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a 3 column `flex` `ul` list with fluid width/height containers.

When I set `height` to `60%`, it creates a gap at the bottom. The `footer text` should be right up against the containers. I need to use `%` instead of `px` so it scales with the browser size.

Setting `max-height` on any of the elements does not seem to remove the gap.

[image: containers]

---

https://jsfiddle.net/8ogm45w0/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="category">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="photo-container">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/By5S6Rd.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">Example</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="photo-container">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/da2NTpb.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">Example</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="photo-container">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RGVB4jY.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">Example</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<hr /> 
Footer
```

**CSS**

```
ul.category {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-height: 300px;
}

ul.category li {
  max-width: 32%;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.photo-container {
  height: 60%;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.photo-container img {
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.4em;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Updated answer:

I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, but at last.. :)

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/30bq4jn5/15/)

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.category {
    height: 60%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: pink;
}

.category a {
    height: 100%;
    width: 32%;
}

.photo-container {
    height: 100%;
}

.photo-container img {
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
}

.title {
    height: 10%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #000;
}
```

Comment: That was a mistake, I only put 300px in there for example to show it didnt affect it, and removed them in the updated link. I have to use `%` instead of `px`. Look when you scale your jsfiddle, the titles detach from the photos.

Comment: @MattMcManis I've just updated my answer with your desired result, let me know what you think.

Comment: It is closer, though now it stretches the images when scaling. Where as it originally kept the aspect and cropped it with `overflow: hidden;`. I'm having to use several media queries to adjust it for each page size for now because I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: The images are going to stretch if you're applying a % height, that is expected. If you don't want this, you can always apply a fixed height in px. What is the problem with this?